# Python Client - Always Receives 401 error

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I am trying to use the Python library for Coinbase's API, but I receive a 401 error on every request. I tried with a Sandbox account, with a new API key (with every permission) but I get a `401` on every single authenticated request.

Here is my code:

```
from coinbase.client import Client

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

client.get_buy_price() # works fine
client.get_accounts() # not working at all
```

For example, here is a sample with my sandbox key/secret (this pair has full permissions):

```
from coinbase.client import Client

API_KEY = "b9hXalyQoZ8z4Dk2"
API_SECRET = "fALfigoBfHU6uLcFbWbmPf5NRwgMX9c6"

client = Client(API_KEY, API_SECRET)

print client.get_buy_price() # gets the price correctly
print client.get_accounts() # raises a 401
```

Comment: Have you read this: https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/permissions ?

Comment: @alfasin Yes. Both the Sandbox API key and regular API key have full permissions, so I should be allowed to do this. It was working yesterday and I haven't made any changes to the permissions so I'm not sure what changed. My thoughts right now are that the Coinbase API is having some bug. I tried generating numerous API keys with full permissions but all of them receive the 401 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a temporary outage on the API that affected a small number of customers. It should be fixed now.